# Angular 2 RC1 - Cannot find default outlet

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

I am trying to upgrade from Angular 2 beta.17 to Angular 2 RC1 and am getting the following exception, when clicking on a routeLink in menu (html), please any ideas would be helpful on what I am doing wrong.

```
browser_adapter.ts:78 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot find default outlet
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:538)
    at zone.js:574
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.ts:56)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:355)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:256)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:474)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:426)
```

Please see my code below...

App:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {LoggedInRouterOutlet} from "../../common/directives/logged-in-router-outlet.directive";
import {HeaderComponent} from "../../common/components/header.component";
import {ErrorComponent} from "../../common/components/error.component";
import {AlertComponent} from "../../common/components/alert.component";
import {MenuComponent} from "../../common/components/menu.component";
import {FooterComponent} from "../../common/components/footer.component";
import {router} from "../../routes/routes";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [HeaderComponent, ErrorComponent, AlertComponent, MenuComponent, FooterComponent, LoggedInRouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: 'modules/app/components/app.html'
})
@Routes(router.config)
export class AppComponent {
}
```

App (html):

```
<header></header>

<error></error>

<alert></alert>

<menu></menu>

<div class="section">
    <logged-in-router-outlet></logged-in-router-outlet>
</div>

<footer></footer>
```

Routes:

```
import {HomeComponent} from '../home/components/home.component';
import {LoginComponent} from '../login/components/login.component';
import {CustomerSearchComponent} from '../customer/components/search.component';

export const router = {
    // confirm , useAsDefault: true does not work anymore
    config: [
        {path: '/home', component: HomeComponent, name: 'Home'},
        {path: '/login', component: LoginComponent, name: 'Login'},
        {path: '/customer_search', component: CustomerSearchComponent, name: 'CustomerSearch'},
        {path: '*', component: HomeComponent}
    ]
};
```

Bootstrap:

```
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/router";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/http";
import {bootstrap} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import {enableProdMode} from "@angular/core";

import {AppComponent} from "../app/components/app.component";

import {AuthenticationService} from "../common/services/authentication.service";
import {RequestService} from "../common/services/request.service";
import {NotificationService} from "../common/services/notification.service";
import {Base64Service} from "../common/services/base64.service";
import {ValidationService} from "../common/services/validation.service";

enableProdMode(); 

bootstrap(AppComponent,
  [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    AuthenticationService,
    RequestService,
    NotificationService,
    Base64Service,
    ValidationService
  ]);
```

Router (directive):

```
import {ElementRef, DynamicComponentLoader, AttributeMetadata, Directive} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../services/authentication.service';
import {RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router/src/directives/router_outlet'; 

@Directive({
  selector: 'logged-in-router-outlet'
})
export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
  publicRoutes = [
    'home', 'login'
  ];

  static get parameters() {
    return [[ElementRef], [DynamicComponentLoader], [Router], [new AttributeMetadata('name'), String], [AuthenticationService]];
  }

  constructor(elementRef, componentLoader, parentRouter, name, authenticationService) {
    super(elementRef, componentLoader, parentRouter, name);

    this.parentRouter = parentRouter;
    this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
  }

  activate(instruction) {
    if (this._canActivate(instruction.urlPath)) {
      return super.activate(instruction);
    }

    this.parentRouter.navigate(['login']);
  }

  _canActivate(url) {
    return this.publicRoutes.indexOf(url) !== -1 || this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

Menu:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {AuthenticationService} from "../services/authentication.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'menu',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: 'modules/common/components/menu.html'
})
export class MenuComponent {
  router;

  static get parameters() {
    return [[Router],[AuthenticationService]];
  }

  constructor(router, authenticationService) {
    this.router = router;
    this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.authenticationService.getLoggedIn();
  }

  logout() {
    this.authenticationService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Menu (html):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['home']">Home</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu-navbar-collapse" data-ng-controller="MenuController">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Customer <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['customer_search']">Search</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" *ngIf="!(isLoggedIn() | async)">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Login or Register <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['login']"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" *ngIf="(isLoggedIn() | async)">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED based of answer supplied below.**

Exception:

```
TypeError: this._parentRouter.registerPrimaryOutlet is not a function
    at LoggedInRouterOutlet.RouterOutlet (router_outlet.ts:46)
    at new LoggedInRouterOutlet (logged-in-router-outlet.directive.js:108)
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent0.createInternal (AppComponent.template.js:61)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (view.ts:110)
    at DebugAppView.create (view.ts:315)
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (AppComponent_Host.template.js:17)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (view.ts:110)
    at DebugAppView.create (view.ts:315)
    at ComponentFactory.create (component_factory.ts:96)
    at eval (application_ref.ts:359)
```

Router (directive):

```
import {ElementRef, DynamicComponentLoader, AttributeMetadata, Directive} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../services/authentication.service';
import {RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router-deprecated'; // TODO: temp replace with rc2 as that exports it

@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})
export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
  publicRoutes = [
    'home', 'login'
  ];

  static get parameters() {
    return [[ElementRef], [DynamicComponentLoader], [Router], [new AttributeMetadata('name'), String], [AuthenticationService]];
  }

  constructor(elementRef, componentLoader, parentRouter, name, authenticationService) {
    super(elementRef, componentLoader, parentRouter, name);

    this.parentRouter = parentRouter;
    this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
  }

  activate(instruction) {
    if (this._canActivate(instruction.urlPath)) {
      return super.activate(instruction);
    }

    this.parentRouter.navigate(['login']);
  }

  _canActivate(url) {
    return this.publicRoutes.indexOf(url) !== -1 || this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

App (html):

```
<header></header>

<error></error>

<alert></alert>

<menu></menu>

<div class="section">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with @angular/router 3.0.0-alpha.6. I followed this Plnkr as an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ER0tf8fpGHZiuVWB7Q07.

My error went away when importing the ROUTER_DIRECTIVES from @angular/router when the Component uses a

```
<router-outlet>
```

in the template. Like this:

```
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES].
```

Please check the Plnkr. And especially app.component.ts and app/crisis-center/crisis-center.component.ts. Both import the ROUTER_DIRECTIVES.

Comment: Thank you very much I will take a look and see if applying the same fixes my issue.

Comment: No problem, I hope this helped you!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8427

The selector needs to be the same as the original router outlet `selector: 'router-outlet'` in RC.1

**Hint**

The `@angular/router` is deprecated as well. A new (or reworked) router is work in progress. Currently it's probably better to stick with `@angular/router-deprecated` until the new new router is out.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your response, I agree this does seem like the same issue.  When I make the recommended changes though I now get a separate error.  TypeError: this._parentRouter.registerPrimaryOutlet is not a function, please see my question above updated to see the changes I made and the stacktrace of the error, if you have an idea around this it would be appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't have other ideas. A new router *angain* will be shipped soon. I'm not sure it's a good idea to spend lots of time on the current router.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be that RC1 router is  deprecated as well.

> A little more than a month ago, we introduced a new router at ng-conf.
>   We hoped this would finally resolve the outstanding routing issues in
>   our first design.
>
> It turns out, routing is hard.
>
> We’re grateful to have heard from many folks at ng-conf about flaws in
>   this new design, so we are announcing version 3.0.0-alpha.3 of
>   @angular/router and are deprecating version 2. You should begin using
>   this router right away.

http://angularjs.blogspot.de/2016/06/improvements-coming-for-routing-in.html

They recommend to upgrade routing to a new version and have some plunkr for it

> Get started by checking out this plunker, stay tuned for more about
>   this Router, and the upcoming Angular 2 RC2.

It seems that neither RC1 nor version 3.0.0-alpha.3 are stable. So it is up to you which version use either @angular/router-deprecated or version 3.0.0-alpha.3. But RC1 has even not a lot of documentation and I wouldn't suggest to use. You can also look alternatively at [ui-router-ng2](https://github.com/ui-router/quickstart-ng2)

Comment: I think I'm going to have to hold off until the new router is released, thanks for your explanation and time.